Recurrence Relation for path in grid
I have been working on problems of grid where we start at (0,0) and have to find the number of ways to reach (n,m) provided we can only move up or right. The solution to this using direct formula by using combinatorics had been understood by me but can it have a recurrence relation?
For example from (0,0) to (1,1) there are 2 paths. Now if we have to go from (0,0) to (2,2) we see that we can use the number of ways to reach to (1,1) first and then use it to solve the bigger problem with 2 more solutions: rruu and uurr. Now if we again consider going from (0,0) to (3,3) then we can actually go to (1,1) and then use the solutions of [(0,0)->(2,2)] to reach (3,3) with some additional paths along the side. Can we generalize it? Any resource would also be helpful.

If $n,m \geq 1$, every path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$ consists of going either from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m-1)$ and $(n,m-1)$ to $(n,m)$ (or) $(0,0)$ to $(n-1,m)$ and $(n-1,m)$ to $(n,m)$. Now think of adding these two recursively.
